# WPF equivalent to Bitmap.LockBits

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, image, image-processing

I have the following working code in a Win Forms application:

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(imageWidth, imageHeight, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight);
BitmapData bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

Tao.DevIl.Il.ilConvertImage(Tao.DevIl.Il.IL_BGRA, Tao.DevIl.Il.IL_UNSIGNED_BYTE);
Tao.DevIl.Il.ilCopyPixels(0, 0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight, 1, Tao.DevIl.Il.IL_BGRA, Tao.DevIl.Il.IL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bitmapData.Scan0);

bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
```

I would like to convert this code to be compatible with WPF and displayable in the UI. This means I will probably have to convert the System.Drawing.Bitmap to a System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage.

However, instead of converting between the two, I was wondering if there's a directer/faster way to do this? Like doing something like LockBits() on the BitmapImage.

The ilCopyPixels() takes a IntPtr as last baram. In the old code I'm getting this form BitmapData.Scan0.

Edit:

Thanks to Erno's answer I came up with the following:

```
WriteableBitmap bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(imageWidth, imageHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgra32, null);
bitmap.Lock();
Tao.DevIl.Il.ilCopyPixels(0, 0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight, 1, Tao.DevIl.Il.IL_BGRA, Tao.DevIl.Il.IL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bitmap.BackBuffer);
bitmap.Unlock();
```

However, when I set the bitmap as the source of an image I don't see anything. I'm not getting any exceptions though.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current temp fix I have is to convert the Bitmap to a BitmapSource using the following code:

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(imageWidth, imageHeight, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight);
BitmapData bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

Tao.DevIl.Il.ilCopyPixels(0, 0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight, 1, Tao.DevIl.Il.IL_BGRA, Tao.DevIl.Il.IL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bitmapData.Scan0);
Tao.DevIl.Il.ilDeleteImages(1, ref imageId);

bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);

using (MemoryStream str = new MemoryStream())
{
    bitmap.Save(str, ImageFormat.Bmp);
    str.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    BitmapDecoder bdc = new BmpBitmapDecoder(str, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
    // Retrieve the BitmapSource
    image1.Source = bdc.Frames[0];
}
```

Obviously, I would rather create a BitmapSource directly without the extra overhead of creating a Bitmap first. Any suggestions are still welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [WriteableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx) it takes care of most of these details.

Comment: Could you show how you are assigning the bitmap as a source of an image? I am also a bit worried about all the parameters in the iLCopyPixels. The pixelformat must be correct. Could you try to copy the pixels to an array and then assign the Pixels property of the bitmap?

Comment: I'm just setting the Source property of an Image to my WriteableBitmap. I'm using the Tao framework, so have no other choice than CopyPixels. I hope it works with an array, will see.

Comment: Btw, Bitmap and WriteableBitmap both do not have a Pixels property.

Comment: Sorry, I tend to mix up the WPF and the Silverlight WriteableBitmaps.